# Views with temporay background helper images

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've searched google and maybe missing a key word....

Theres a few iphone apps that display background grey helper images for a few seconds the first time as user acceses the view. These normally indicate theres additional information off screen or a particular guesture does something. They are only displayed the first time the view is used for a few seconds and are transparent grey.

Are there any examples available showing how to acheive this affect, if not what API's should I investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

The affect is basically

1. Create view with default image
2. Start downloading stuff
3. When downloading completes, set image

(I'm assuming it's not an animation, where you just change the image by setting a new one after a short, fixed delay.)